# Find the value of p for which the following series converges?

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots )\in l^4$, $x\neq 0$. For which one of the following values of $p$, the series
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i y_i
$$
converges for every $y = (y_1, y_2, \ldots )\in l^p$?

- A) 1
- B) 2
- C) 3
- D) 4

**What I tried:** I tried to use Hölder's inequality, I am almost done, I think I am just missing a little.

$|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i y_i|\le
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i y_i|\le ||x||_4 ||y||_p $

where $p$ is the Hölder conjugate of $4$ which gives $p=4/3$.

Comment: "I have tried to use the Holder's inequality to get something" Excellent! Please show how you tried.

Comment: Right -- and this points clearly at a unique correct option... But maybe what you are missing is that the family of spaces $(\ell^p)_{p>0}$ is increasing... Thus, you might want to show this fact and then to apply it to your setting.

Comment: Is it $||y||_{4/3}\le ||y||_1$ impling that p= 1 will work??

Comment: Well, $\ell^1\subset\ell^{4/3}\subset\ell^2\subset\ell^3\subset\ell^4$ and every $y$ in $\ell^{4/3}$ works, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in \ell^{q}$ for every $q \in [1,\infty]$ then the series converges in all 4 cases. Assume that $x \in \ell^{4}\setminus \ell^{q}$ for all $q <4$. In this case the answer is A).  You  already know that the series converges if $y \in \ell ^{4/3}$. If $y \in \ell ^{p}$ with $p \leq \frac 4 3$ then $y \in \ell ^{4/3}$ so the series converges. To show that the series may not converge in cases B), C) and D) take $y_n=sign(x_n)|x_n|^{\alpha}$ for a suitable $\alpha$. I will leave the details to you.

Comment: That pretty much helps the deal